# Eazfuscator.NET. Disable sealing

Tags: eazfuscator

I need to disable Sealing of Terminal Classes feature. But I cannot find which name I should use for ObfuscationAttribute.

I tried this:

```
[Obfuscation(Feature = "sealing", Exclude = true)]
class MyClass {
}
```

But it does not work.

Where I can find names for all Eazfuscator.NET features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `auto-sealing` instead of `sealing`:

```
[Obfuscation(Feature = "auto-sealing", Exclude = true)]
class MyClass
{
}
```

The official support for `sealing` alternative name will be available since Eazfuscator.NET 2019.4+.

Comment: Works as akspected. Thanks. Where I can find a complete list of possible names for each feature?

Comment: Eazfuscator.NET help at https://help.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net documents most of directives, but not all of them (there are plenty of unofficial and thus undocumented ones).

Comment: I am aware of this documentation. But I didn’t see auto-sealing there =)